# If $A$ is a primitive / irreducible C*-algebra, then $M(A)$ has trivial center.

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Recall some definitions: a sub-C*-algebra $A$ of $B(H)$, the algebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$, is called *irreducible* if the only closed $A$-invariant subspaces of $H$ are $0$ and $H$ itself. A (general) C*-algebra $A$ is called *primitive* if there is a irreducible faithful representation of $A$ in some $B(H)$. We denote $M(A)$ the [Multiplier Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_algebra) of $A$.

> How do we show that if $A$ is primitive then $Z(M(A))$ (the center of $M(A)$) is trivial, that is, $Z=\mathbb{C}\cdot 1$?

I looked for this, and there are in fact some places where this is stated (for example, [this answer in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/120557)), but I couldn't find the proof anywhere.

The first problem I encountered is "Given $p\in Z(M(A))$, how do I find a candidate $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ for which $p=\lambda1$?". After reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608330/58818) of the question [How do we show that prime C* algebras have trivial center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603935/how-do-we-show-that-prime-c-algebras-have-trivial-center), I tought of using Gelfand-Mazur theorem. It is clear that $Z(M(A))$ is a Banach algebra, so the problem is to show, using irreducibility of $A$, that it is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $A\subset M(A)\subset B(H)$ (since $A''=B(H)$). So an element of the centre of $M(A)$ commutes with all the elements of $A$. Then
$$
Z(M(A))\subset A'=A'''=B(H)'=\mathbb C\ I.
$$

Comment: I just don't see why $A''=B(H)$ implies $M(A)\subseteq B(H)$. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: If you represent your C$^*$-algebra $A$ faithfully in $B(H)$, it is a theorem that $M(A)$ can be represented inside $A''$. I remember it from Pedersen's book, which I don't have at hand right now.

Comment: Thank you. Just for reference, the result Martin Argerami cited is Proposition 3.12.3 of Pedersen's *$C^*$-algebras and their Automorphism Groups*.

Comment: Because $A$ is irreducible.